# AJAX .post method not passing data to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a program and am having trouble passing user credentials into a database. I am using the AJAX .post function and for some reason, the data is not being passed into the PHP script.

The submitInfo() function seems to completely bypass the .post function nested inside, as the page does notify me with the successful sign in alert after pressing submit.

Here is the HTML/JS file, (doesn't show the implementation of jQuery along with an imported MD5 function I'm utilizing to hash the password):

```
<h2>First name:<h2>
<input id="firstNameInput" type="text" maxLength="20">

<h2>Last name:<h2>
<input id="lastNameInput" type="text" maxLength="20">

<h2>Create a username:<h2>
<input id="createUserInput" type="text" maxLength="20">

<h2>Create a password:<h2>
<input id="createPassInput" type="text" maxLength="20">
</br>
</br>
<input id="submitCredsButton" type="submit" onclick="submitInfo()">

<script>
function submitInfo()
{
var postData = [{
  firstName : document.getElementById("firstNameInput"),
  lastName : document.getElementById("lastNameInput"),
  username : document.getElementById("createUserInput"),
  hashPass : MD5((document.getElementById("createPassInput")).value)
}];

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "phpScripts/signup.php",
  data: "postData",
  dataType: "text",
});

alert("Sign up Successful! Please log in to enter.");
window.open("login.php", "_self");
}
</script>
```

And here is the PHP script, in a separate file:

```
<?php
$servername = "*****";
$username   = "*****";
$password   = "*****";
$dbname     = "*****";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);    
  }

//posts data to db
$stmt = $data->('INSERT INTO userlist 
(firstName,lastName,username,hashedPass)
        VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :username, :hashPass)');

$stmt->execute($data);
?>
```

-edit-
Figured it all out, one simple but overlooked mistake I had was where I had placed the single and double quotes. Thanks to all users that helped with the JS issues I was having!

HTML/JS:

```
<h2>First name:<h2>
<input id="firstNameInput" type="text" maxLength="20">

<h2>Last name:<h2>
<input id="lastNameInput" type="text" maxLength="20">

<h2>Create a username:<h2>
<input id="createUserInput" type="text" maxLength="20">

<h2>Create a password:<h2>
<input id="createPassInput" type="text" maxLength="20">
</br>
</br>
<input id="submitCredsButton" type="submit" onclick="submitInfo()">

<script>
function submitInfo()
{
    var fName =  document.getElementById("firstNameInput").value;
    var lName =  document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value;
    var uName =  document.getElementById("createUserInput").value;
    var pPass =  document.getElementById("createPassInput").value;
    var hPass =  MD5((document.getElementById("createPassInput")).value);

if(fName.length <= 0 || lName.length <= 0 || uName.length <= 0 || pPass.length <= 0)
{
  alert("Please verify all fields have been filled out.");
}
else
{
  $.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "phpScripts/signup.php",
    data: {firstName: fName, lastName: lName, userName: uName, hashPass: hPass},
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response)
      {
        alert("Sign up Successful! Please log in to enter.");
        window.open("login.php", "_self");
      }
  });
}




}
</script>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php


$servername = "******";
$username = "******";
$password = "******";
$dbname = "******";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }

?>


<?php
//posts data to db
$fName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lName = $_POST["lastName"];
$uName = $_POST["userName"];
$hPass = $_POST["hashPass"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO userlist ( firstName,lastName,username,hashedPass )
        VALUES ( '$fName', '$lName','$uName','$hPass' )" ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result){
echo "true";
}
else{
echo "false";
}


?>
```

Comment: Change - `data: "postData",` - to - `data: postData,` and remove `[` `]` in your `postData` value.

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns `DOM` element. You should get the values of input. Try giving `name` attribute to input fields and then get their value as `$('input[name="input-name"]').val();` using jQuery.

Comment: Show success message inside success callback of ajax. As it is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem. You are not passing a `string` to the `$.ajax`. You have to pass the variable which is an `object`: `data: postData,`.

Second problem. Your `postData` is an `array` but it has to be an `object`:

```
var postData = {
  firstName : document.getElementById("firstNameInput"),
  lastName : document.getElementById("lastNameInput"),
  username : document.getElementById("createUserInput"),
  hashPass : MD5((document.getElementById("createPassInput")).value)
};
```

Third problem. Your are passing `DOM objects` as `postData` instead of their values. Just use `.value` property:

```
var postData = {
  firstName : document.getElementById("firstNameInput").value,
  lastName : document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value,
  username : document.getElementById("createUserInput").value,
  hashPass : MD5((document.getElementById("createPassInput")).value)
};
```

Fourth problem. The `$.ajax` is asynchronous so you have to provide a success callback, so the callback will be run just after the finish of the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "phpScripts/signup.php",
    data: postData,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function () {
        alert("Sign up Successful! Please log in to enter.");
        window.open("login.php", "_self");
    }
});
```

Complete solution:

```
function submitInfo()
{
    var postData = {
      firstName : document.getElementById("firstNameInput").value,
      lastName : document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value,
      username : document.getElementById("createUserInput").value,
      hashPass : MD5((document.getElementById("createPassInput")).value)
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "phpScripts/signup.php",
        data: postData,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function () {
            alert("Sign up Successful! Please log in to enter.");
            window.open("login.php", "_self");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This has helped me tremendously, however I am still not able to get the data posted. I have edited some of the PHP code for testing, where I hardcode strings (such as "testFirstName", "testLastName") into the database, and that works, however whenever I try and pull the variables that were supposed to be posted, it does not work

Comment: @A.Teoxon can you paste here what do you have in the `$_POST` variable when you submit the form?

Comment: I've actually figured it out! I'll edit the original post to show all the code that works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You have written "postData" in double quote, so it will consider as string, but actually it is variable.

Try :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "phpScripts/signup.php",
  data: postData,
  dataType: "text",
});
```

Comment: exactly this is simple.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using **"postData"** which is just a string but you need to use **postData** because it already has definition.

Just replace **"postData"**

with **postData**

**Ajax**

```
    $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "phpScripts/signup.php",
   data: postData,
   dataType: "text",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your postData is an object does not need to so round in quotes "" and include a success call back and in success call back try to redirect on login page. Try this:

```
<script>
function submitInfo()
{
var postData = [{
  firstName : document.getElementById("firstNameInput"),
  lastName : document.getElementById("lastNameInput"),
  username : document.getElementById("createUserInput"),
  hashPass : MD5((document.getElementById("createPassInput")).value)
}];

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "phpScripts/signup.php",
  data: postData,
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(response){
      alert("Sign up Successful! Please log in to enter.");
      window.open("login.php", "_self");
  }
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of _why_ the OP should try the code. What have you changed? Why?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you can check my  answer :)

Comment: Edited please check.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you needs to get value of textboxs. And also in Ajax function you need to pass as a Object (Currently you are passing as String)

```
<script>
function submitInfo()
{
var postData = [{
  firstName : document.getElementById("firstNameInput").value,
  lastName : document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value,
  username : document.getElementById("createUserInput").value,
  hashPass : MD5(document.getElementById("createPassInput").value)
}];

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "phpScripts/signup.php",
  data: postData,
  dataType: "text",
});

alert("Sign up Successful! Please log in to enter.");
window.open("login.php", "_self");
}
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns single `DOM` element of matching id, why are you treating its output as an array? It will throw an error.

Comment: @A. Teoxon
Could you please take a look

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax() in an asynchronous function. You need to use its success(result,status,xhr) callback to show actual success message.

What you are doing is show the success alert outside Ajax call.

The code should be:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "phpScripts/signup.php",
  data: postData,
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
data: "postData",
```

With

```
data: postData,
```

And add success variable after `dataType: "text",`

```
success: function(res){
    if(res=="true"){
        alert("Sign up Successful! Please log in to enter.");
    }
    else{
        alert("something went wrong.");
    }
}
```

and add this line in your php script after `$stmt->execute($data);`

```
$result=$stmt->execute($data);
if($result){
    echo "true";
}
else{
    echo "false";
}
```